# Issue when accessing objects from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to access an `NSArray` and I'm failing somehow (example: I save it and load it from `NSUserDefaults`):

**Saving:**

```
-(id)init{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"set1"] == nil ){

    NSMutableArray* aux =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
    [aux addObject:@1];
    [aux addObject:@2];
    [aux addObject:@3];
    [aux addObject:@0];
    [defaults setObject:aux forKey:@"set1"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"sound"];
}

return [super init];
}
```

**Loading:**

```
-(void)onEnter{
    [super onEnter];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray* save = [[defaults arrayForKey:@"set1"] mutableCopy];

    CCLOG(@"%@",save);
    [_S1 showStars:((int)[save objectAtIndex:0])];
    [_S2 showStars:((int)[save objectAtIndex:1])];
    [_S3 showStars:((int)[save objectAtIndex:2])];
    [_S4 showStars:((int)[save objectAtIndex:3])];
    }
```

Somehow I'm missing something and I get this in return from `CCLOG(@"%@",save);`

```
2014-10-29 16:15:32.155 IM[2091:70b] (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    0
)
```

From printing each object with `CCLOG(@"%i",((int)[save objectAtIndex:0]))`

```
2014-10-29 16:15:32.156 IM[2091:70b] 176633792
2014-10-29 16:15:32.156 IM[2091:70b] 176633808
2014-10-29 16:15:32.157 IM[2091:70b] 159857616
2014-10-29 16:15:32.157 IM[2091:70b] 159857632
```

I've tried a few things and nothing works.

Sorry if it is a dumb question, I'm really new to `Objective-C`.

Comment: NSArray elements are objects.  You can't print them as ints without first converting them into ints.  Casting the pointer to int only gives you the int view of the pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks is right. You can get the integer values by sending `integerValue` to each of your objects.

Comment: And your code for your `init` method is all wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks, can you post your response as an answer so the OP can accept it and it gets marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

NSArray elements are objects. You can't print them as ints without first converting them into ints. Casting the pointer to int only gives you the int view of the pointer itself (and hence the integer you print is a large, "random" number).

To actually print the value of an NSArray element that happens to be an NSNumber you may:

1. Print, using `%@` formatting, the actual object (not the pointer cast to `int`).
2. Convert the object to `int` form using the `intValue` method (or to `NSInteger` form using the `integerValue` method, or to `long` form using the `longValue`, etc).

Do note that solution #1 should only be used for NSLog statements, not "production" code, since `%@` formatting invokes the `description` method of the object which is not guaranteed to produce a consistent representation (though it's hard to imagine how not for NSNumber).

Also note that if the object in question is *not* an NSNumber or an NSString then `intValue`, et al, will throw a runtime error.